# Find how many times each number between N and M can be expressed as a sum of a pair of primes

Tags: java, algorithm, math, optimization, time-complexity

Consider this method:

```
public static int[] countPairs(int min, int max) {
    int lastIndex = primes.size() - 1;
    int i = 0;
    int howManyPairs[] = new int[(max-min)+1];

    for(int outer : primes) {
        for(int inner : primes.subList(i, lastIndex)) {
            int sum = outer + inner;

            if(sum > max)
                break;

            if(sum >= min && sum <= max)
                howManyPairs[sum - min]++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return howManyPairs;
}
```

As you can see, I have to count how many times each number between min and max can be expressed as a sum of two primes.

`primes` is an ArrayList with all primes between 2 and 2000000. In this case, `min` is 1000000 and `max` is 2000000, that's why primes goes until 2000000.

My method works fine, but the goal here is to do something faster.

My method takes two loops, one inside the other, and it makes my algorithm an O(n²). It sucks like bubblesort.

How can I rewrite my code to accomplish the same result with a better complexity, like O(nlogn)?

One last thing: I'm coding in Java, but your reply can be in also Python, VB.Net, C#, Ruby, C or even just a explanation in English.

Comment: Almost makes me wish I was better at number theory...almost.

Comment: This sounds like it would be a better fit on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it doesn't seem to be about a specific problem but rather a request for improvement of working code.

Comment: Working code looking for advice would be a better fit on [codereview.se], but when you put this question there, it should be a complete, working program (including a `main` method) and you should expect to receive all sorts of comments, on style as well as algorithm complexity.

Comment: A [fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) would do the job. I'm writing up a more detailed explanation of how it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each number `x` between `min` and `max`, we want to compute the number of ways `x` can be written as the sum of two primes. This number can also be expressed as

```
sum(prime(n)*prime(x-n) for n in xrange(x+1))
```

where `prime(x)` is 1 if x is prime and 0 otherwise. Instead of counting the number of ways that two primes add up to `x`, we consider all ways two nonnegative integers add up to `x`, and add 1 to the sum if the two integers are prime.

This isn't a more efficient way to do the computation. However, putting it in this form helps us recognize that the output we want is the [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) of two sequences. Specifically, if `p` is the infinite sequence such that `p[x] == prime(x)`, then the convolution of `p` with itself is the sequence such that

```
convolve(p, p)[x] == sum(p[n]*p[x-n] for n in xrange(x+1))
```

or, substituting the definition of `p`,

```
convolve(p, p)[x] == sum(prime(n)*prime(x-n) for n in xrange(x+1))
```

In other words, convolving `p` with itself produces the sequence of numbers we want to compute.

The straightforward way to compute a convolution is pretty much what you were doing, but there are much faster ways. For `n`-element sequences, a [fast Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)-based algorithm can compute the convolution in `O(n*log(n))` time instead of `O(n**2)` time. Unfortunately, this is where my explanation ends. Fast Fourier transforms are kind of hard to explain even when you have proper mathematical notation available, and as my memory of the Cooley-Tukey algorithm isn't as precise as I'd like it to be, I can't really do it justice.

If you want to read more about [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and [Fourier transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), particularly the [Cooley-Tukey FFT algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm), the Wikipedia articles I've just linked would be a decent start. If you just want to use a faster algorithm, your best bet would be to get a library that does it. In Python, I know [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) would do the job; in other languages, you could probably find a library pretty quickly through your search engine of choice.

Comment: I talked to my professor. He said this answer is probably the best I can do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you´re searching is the count of [Goldbach partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) for each number
in your range, and imho there is no efficient algorithm for it.

Uneven numbers have 0, even numbers below `4*10^18` are guaranteed to have more than 0,
but other than that... to start with, if even numbers (bigger than `4*10^18`) with 0 partitions exist
is an unsolved problem since 1700-something, and such things as exact numbers are even more complicated.

There are some asymptotic and heuristic solutions, but if you want the exact number,
other than getting more CPU and RAM, there isn´t be much you can do.

Comment: You can still reduce the number of iterations, which will more than double performance, by adding an upper boundary to the outer loop and a lower boundary to the inner loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you are referring to odd/even numbers. OP already has a list of prime numbers, and are only iterating those. The code is *not* iterating *all* numbers in a range, so the issue of odd/even is meaningless.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, brain fart, and doing too much things simultaneously. Deleted that comment. Well, other than that, I didn´t want to say that OPs solution is the best in the world, but something like `O(n*logn)` (like asked) is unreachable (with todays knowledge)

Comment: Yeah, even with loop boundary optimizations, it's still a brute-force solution.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have an outer loop that goes from N to M. It's more efficient, however, for the outer loop (or loops) to be pairs of primes, used to build a list of numbers between N and M that equal their sums.

Since I don't know Java I'll give a solution in Ruby for a specific example. That should allow anyone interested to implement the algorithm in Java, regardless of whether they know Ruby.

I initially assume that two primes whose product equals a number between M and N must be unique. In other words, `4` cannot be express as `4 = 2+2`.

Use Ruby's prime number library.

```
require 'prime'
```

Assume M and N are 5 and 50.

```
lower =  5
upper = 50
```

Compute the prime numbers up to `upper-2 #=> 48`, the `2` being the first prime number.

```
primes = Prime.each.take_while { |p| p < upper-2 }
  #=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

Construct an enumerator of all combinations of two primes.

```
enum = primes.combination(2)
  => #<Enumerator: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]:combination(2)>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[2, 3], [2, 5],..., [2, 47], [3, 5],..., [43, 47]] (105 elements)
```

Just think of `enum` as an array.

Now construct a counting hash whose keys are numbers between `lower` and `upper` for which there is at least one pair of primes that sum to that number and whose values are the numbers of pairs of primes that sum to the value of the associated key.

```
enum.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(x,y),h|
  sum = x+y
  h[sum] += 1 if (lower..upper).cover?(sum)
end
  #=> {5=>1, 7=>1, 9=>1, 13=>1, 15=>1, 19=>1, 21=>1, 25=>1, 31=>1, 33=>1,
  #    39=>1, 43=>1, 45=>1, 49=>1, 8=>1, 10=>1, 14=>1, 16=>2, 20=>2, 22=>2,
  #    26=>2, 32=>2, 34=>3, 40=>3, 44=>3, 46=>3, 50=>4, 12=>1, 18=>2, 24=>3,
  #    28=>2, 36=>4, 42=>4, 48=>5, 30=>3, 38=>1}
```

This shows, for example, that there are two ways that `16` can be expressed as the sum of two primes (`3+13` and `5+11`), three ways for `34` (`3+31`, `5+29` and `11+23`) and no way for `6`.

If the two primes being summed need not be unique (e.g., `4=2+2` is to be included), only a slight change is needed.

```
arr = primes.combination(2).to_a.concat(primes.zip(primes))
```

whose sorted values are

```
a = arr.sort
  #=> [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 5], [2, 7],..., [3, 3],..., [5, 5],.., [47, 47]] (120 elements)
```

then

```
a.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(x,y),h|
  sum = x+y
  h[sum] += 1 if (lower..upper).cover?(sum)
end
  #=> {5=>1, 7=>1, 9=>1, 13=>1, 15=>1, 19=>1, 21=>1, 25=>1, 31=>1, 33=>1,
  #    39=>1, 43=>1, 45=>1, 49=>1, 6=>1, 8=>1, 10=>2, 14=>2, 16=>2, 20=>2,
  #    22=>3, 26=>3, 32=>2, 34=>4, 40=>3, 44=>3, 46=>4, 50=>4, 12=>1, 18=>2,
  #    24=>3, 28=>2, 36=>4, 42=>4, 48=>5, 30=>3, 38=>2}
```

`a` should be replaced by `arr`. I used `a` here merely to order the elements of the resulting hash so that it would be easier to read.

Since I just wanted to describe the approach, I used a brute force method to enumerate the pairs of elements of `primes`, throwing away 44 of the 120 pairs of primes because their sums fall outside the range `5..50` (`a.count { |x,y| !(lower..upper).cover?(x+y) } #=> 44`). Clearly, there's considerable room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

A sum of two primes means `N = A + B`, where `A` and `B` are primes, and `A < B`, which means `A < N / 2` and `B > N / 2`. Note that they can't be equal to `N / 2`.

So, your outer loop should only loop from `1` to `floor((N - 1) / 2)`. In integer math, the `floor` is automatic.

Your inner loop can be eliminated if the primes are stored in a `Set`. Assuming your array is sorted (fair assumption), use a `LinkedHashSet`, such that iterating the set in the outer loop can stop at `(N - 1) / 2`.

I'll leave it up to you to code this.

---

**Update**

Sorry, the above is an answer to the problem of finding `A` and `B` for a particular `N`. Your question was to find all `N` between `min` and `max` (inclusive).

If you follow to logic of the above, you should be able to apply that to your problem.

Outer loop should be from `1` to `max / 2`.
Inner loop should be from `min - outer` to `max - outer`.

To find the starting point of the inner loop, you can keep some extra index variables around, or you can rely on your prime array being sorted and use [`Arrays.binarySearch(primes, min - outer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int[],%20int%29). First option is likely a little bit faster, but second option is definitely simpler.

Comment: Please explain the down-vote.  Note that the OP explicitly states *"or even just a explanation in English"*!!

Comment: @StephenC I think the down-vote was because I didn't answer the question, but it's rude to down-vote without explanation. I have updated my answer to actually answer the question.

Comment: Even a partial answer doesn't deserve a downvote ... in a question like this.  And your original answer was a valid partial answer.  Furthermore, if people are going to down-vote answers like this, I'm not going to spend my time answering.

Comment: @StephenC Please don't let a few *idiot* down-voters discourage you. There are good people that appreciate the help of smart people like you.